# querying database in constructor (java)?

Tags: java, oop

Is it a good practice to execute query in constructor?

```
class Foo {
  public Foo() {
    populateData();
  }

  private void populateData() {
    // query database here...
  }
}
```

Comment: I usually stay away from code that does heavy work in the constructor. Object *creation* should be fast.

Answer (score 7):

Constructor only purpose is to create an instance of a class.

The issue with querying a database is the operation can fail.

At that point if you don't handle exception properly then your code is candidate for bugs.

You should think of constructor a way to prepare the object for use which should be quick.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code to be both legible and extensible, I can advise to consider the [Single_responsibility_principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). According to it -  *every context (class, function, variable, etc.) should have a single responsibility, and that responsibility should be entirely encapsulated by the context. All its services should be narrowly aligned with that responsibility.*

So bottom line is your method to be put to work like this:

```
public static class DbAccessor
{
    public static void setPopulatedData() {
        // query database here...
      }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use lazy values. Google Guava provides some utilities to do that.
e.g.

```
class Foo {

    private final Spplier<Data> data = Suppliers.memoize(new Supplier<Data>() {
  public Data get() {
    // query database here...
    return data;
  };
});

  public Foo() {

  }
}
```